# Destroying in Array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a very weird bug currently which I am hoping someone could help me resolve.

So, in a game I am in the progress of completing, I have a manager that gets disable on game end only and at that point, it would be supposed to destroy all missiles it instantiated. (The game isn't big so I am not scared of instantiate/destroy taking too much memory)

But my problem comes when that code runs.

```
public void OnDisable(){
    GameObject[] temp = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MC_Missile");
    Debug.Log (temp.Length);
    for(int i = 0; i > temp.Length; i++){
        Destroy (temp[i]); 

    }
}
```

When Debug is reached, it returns the correct amount of elements. But then, none of the elements are removed from my scene. I have tried temp[i].gameObject but it still doesn't work. I have also tried reloading Unity in case of a runtime bug but to no result.

So I am stuck on this. (I am on Unity 5.0.0f4 if that can help)

Edit: DestroyImmediate doesn't work also. I'll be trying with a List to see if the array is messing up with Destroy. (Could be a failsafe)

Comment: w.b answer should help you. But I just comment that it is not good to use this method you use for finding objects even if this is small game and small amount of objects. This could enter your blood and be habit even in bigger projects. Instead of it, keep some collection of objects like these missiles. It could be static for easy adding let say on Awake of missle MonoBehaviour script. But there are other problems with static references to GameObjects, but it is not a point here.

Comment: Jerry, don't worry. On anything bigger than this project (which is by the way the limit of what I consider a small project), I implement an Object Pool. I just couldn't had been bothered to do so for this small of a project.

Comment: I see good to hear. Object pool is even better option ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop can't work, try changing the `greater than` to `less than`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
                ^^^^
{
    Destroy (temp[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Herp Derp Derp. Stupid mistake. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Destroy(temp[i].gameObject);
```

Comment: "I have tried temp[i].gameObject but it still doesn't work." I already have.

Comment: Sorry! Just finishing my coffee now and noticed that. I should learn to wait until I finish the cup to start offering advice. The above poster is right about the for loop. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be accepting the answer as soon as I can. (In a few minutes)

Answer (score 0):

your for loop condition is :

```
for(int i = 0; i > temp.Length; i++) // i is 0 so the loop will not run
```

try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
```

Comment: There is exactly same answer already and already accepted :)